# Load a particular certificate from a cert pool (crypto/x509 / tls)

Tags: go, tls1.2

I'm looking at Go package for CA Certs (https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/x509). Instead of loading the whole cert pool, is it possible to load just a single cert we need (by name, id) on x509/tls on Go? I do not see native methods for this on the package and would like to see if anyone implemented or has come across this.

Comment: You'll have to load the whole CA bundle with [ParseCertificates](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/x509#ParseCertificates) and then look through them all for the one you want and  [add](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/x509#CertPool.AddCert) it to an empty cert pool.

Comment: Loading the whole CA bundle created some issues for my case. So I was wondering if I can only load selected certificate.